# PostgreSQL regexp replace function with condition

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

There is a PostgreSQL table. This table has a field which contains the queries of the stored procedures as string.
I am looking for a regexp replace solution which I am able to remove the part of the string with but only in that cases where the string contains 'tmp'.

Example string inputs:

```
...from schema1.table_1...
...from schema1.table_1_tmp...
...from schema1.table_2...
...from schema1.table_2_tmp...
```

Aim:

```
...from schema1.table_1...
...from table_1_tmp...
...from schema1.table_2...
...from table_2_tmp...
```

`schema1` is a static value, only the table names are different. Some of them contains `tmp` substring, some of them not.

If it contains tmp, we should remove the `schema1` string.

Comment: Are you looking for an UPDATE statement to permanently change those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()` as follows:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '\sschema1\.(\w+_tmp)\s', ' \1 ')
```

Regex breakdown:

```
\s           a space
schema1\.    litteral string "schema1."
(            beginning of a capturing group
    \w+          at many alphanumeric characters as possible (including "_")
    _tmp         litteral string "_tmp"
)            end of the capturing group
\s           a space
```

When the string matches the regex, the matching expression is replaced by: a space, then the captured part, then another space.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=89043b015b704569034fb157c3ccea1f)**:

```
with t as (
    select '... from schema1.table_1_tmp ...' mycol
    union all select '... from schema1.table_2 ...'
)
select mycol, regexp_replace(mycol, '\sschema1\.(\w+_tmp)\s', ' \1 ') newcol from t
```

```
mycol                            | newcol                      
:------------------------------- | :---------------------------
... from schema1.table_1_tmp ... | ... from table_1_tmp ...    
... from schema1.table_2 ...     | ... from schema1.table_2 ...
```

Comment: Your explanation is excellent, and it should work, but unfortunatelly not... I tried with your demo code also but not working. Maybe the PostgreSQL version can occour differncies? I am using 8.3.23.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to update your Postgres version; version 8.3.x reached end-of-life in Feb-2013. However, the @GMB answer should work as all the appropriate regexp functions do exist in it. However, you can also try the replace function.

```
with test_tab (tbl) as
     ( values ('...from schema1.table_1...')
            , ('...from schema1.table_1_tmp...')
            , ('...from schema1.table_2...')
            , ('...from schema1.table_2_tmp...')
     )
 select replace(tbl,'schema1.','') "Without Schema"
   from test_tab
  where tbl ilike '%schema1%_tmp%';
```